# Is there an alternative for TrueCrypt?

Tags: macos, truecrypt

[TrueCrypt said](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) it is not secure. What are alternatives?

Comment: If you go to the bottom of the page it gives an answer

Comment: Besides, as of now, the background of the warning is totally unclear.

Comment: The page continues to be unchanged

Answer (score 7):

## Encrypted Disk Images

The TrueCrypt pages suggest using an [encrypted disk image](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/OtherPlatforms.html).

## FileVault

Apple provides drive level encryption through [FileVault](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4790).

> With FileVault 2 you can encrypt the contents of your entire drive to
>   help keep your data secure.
>
> FileVault 2 uses full disk, XTS-AES 128 encryption to help keep your
>   data secure. Using FileVault 2, you can encrypt the contents of your
>   entire drive.

### Alternatives

Other alternatives are discussed at:

- Hacker News, [True Goodbye: ‘Using TrueCrypt Is Not Secure’](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7814725)
- [Windows Encrypted Virtual Hard Drive but not Bitlocker or Truecrypt?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4529/windows-encrypted-virtual-hard-drive-but-not-bitlocker-or-truecrypt) Where cross platform alternatives may be suggested.
- A [Swiss based TrueCrypt group](http://truecrypt.ch) has recently formed; they may provide ongoing support.

### Why not trust TrueCrypt?

TrueCrypt is [warning its users](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net) that it may contain unfixed security issues.

> WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed
>   security issues

The development of TrueCrypt has stopped and thus any newly found bugs may not be fixed:

> The development of TrueCrypt was ended in 5/2014 after Microsoft
>   terminated support of Windows XP. Windows 8/7/Vista and later offer
>   integrated support for encrypted disks and virtual disk images. Such
>   integrated support is also available on other platforms (click here
>   for more information). You should migrate any data encrypted by
>   TrueCrypt to encrypted disks or virtual disk images supported on your
>   platform.

Comment: @dwightk Thank you. Please feel free to edit answers. Spelling, grammar, and general clarity improvements are always welcome!

Comment: yeah, I figured I'd let you get one character rather than go searching for 5 more to change.

Comment: @dwightk Once you hit 2k you can edit a single char too!

Answer (score 2):

Being a fan of AgileBits, I have been using [Knox](https://agilebits.com/knox) since it came out many months ago.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[GPG](https://www.gnupg.org) or the commercial [PGP Pretty Good Privacy](http://philzimmermann.com/EN/findpgp/).

> GnuPG itself is a commandline tool without any graphical stuff. It is
>   the real crypto engine which can be used directly from a command
>   prompt, from shell scripts or by other programs. Therefore it can be
>   considered as a backend for other applications.

[TrueCrypt coninued by others](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm)

Comment: Please add at least an url and explanation how it works please